# What mass is a 'teenth?

Tags: breaking-bad

What is the mass of a 'teenth?  Many characters in Breaking Bad use this term when referring to a small bag of crystal meth (which at one point, when Jesse is buying from the guys that arranged for the death of Combo, costs $300).

It looks to be between 1-3 grams, does that mean it is one 16th of an ounce?  That would come to around 1.75 grams.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have not found any official definition of "teenth", but doing a [Google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=EMuwU8CbEMOnyASu7IKIDA&ved=0CBQQ1S4#q=%22breaking+bad%22+teenth) for the terms "breaking bad" and "teenth", it seems the general consensus is that it does mean 1/16th of an ounce.

Answer (score 17):

As a former drug dealer myself, I can confirm that a "teenth" is, in fact, half of an "eighth", or 1/16th of an ounce (~1.75 grams).  Many "high-potency" drugs are cut that way, because you need less to get high so you buy less at a time.  Particularly Meth, which caters to a low/no income user base where users tend to buy just enough to get them through the day.

Answer (score 0):

All drugs are measured in metric weight. Doctors and pharmacist are the only part of America that established 
The metric pattern in the 70's and 80's. Micro Gram Milligram milliliter and CC all metric weights and measures

Street drugs are Sold in both metric and English.
 So you can purchase a Key or Kilo 2.2 Lbs. 
it's all broken down from there. 16 oz per lb
28.25 grams per Oz. Weed which was once
Sold so cheap a half pound was $65.00 now
A gram is worth the same dollar amount. No
Wonder so many states are going green.

Cocaine was the first drug to command high
Dollars and large profits that is where the term
Eight Ball came from an 8th of an OZ about 4
Grams give or take for $250-300 like buying 
Beer or Soda in 6 packs Verus singles.

I'm figuring a teenth is a 16th of an OZ half if an 
eighth it only Makes since to use that logic. 
Breaking bad is a prime example of how
our political world is governed and intertwined
With the drugs and violence that support corrupt
People at the top.

Comment: The first sentence of the fourth paragraph seems the only one relevant to the question. There are already two better answers that don't have filler not related to the show.